# react-native-svg path does not fill whole svg height

Tags: javascript, css, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

My path fills the SVG horizontally perfectly by vertically it has spacing to the top and bottom as you can see.

How can I remove that spacing and have the path fill the entire height of the SVG element?

Here is my code and a screenshot of the SVG Path. I have colored the SVG background to red so you can see the spacing issue.

[image]

```
<Svg 
  id="chart" 
  width={chartWidth} 
  height={CHART_HEIGHT}>
<Path
  d={data}
  fill='transparent'
  stroke={color}
  strokeWidth={2}></Path>
</Svg>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set `height` property to the `<Path>`? Or set `style={{height: '100%;}}`

Comment: @Azamat Path does not have a height nor a style prop. So it does nothing.